# GraphQL object property should be a list of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

How do I make a schema for an object property that is an array of strings in GraphQL?  I want the response to look like this:

```
{
  name: "colors",
  keys: ["red", "blue"]
}
```

Here is my Schema

```
var keysType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'keys',
  fields: function() {
    key: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
  }
});

var ColorType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'colors',
  fields: function() {
    return {
      name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
      keys: { type: new graphql.GraphQLList(keysType)
    };
  }
});
```

When I run this query I get an error and no data, the error is just `[{}]`

*query { colors { name, keys } }*

However when I run a query to return just the name I get a successful response.

*query { colors { name } }*

How do I create a schema that returns an array of strings for when I query for keys?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  The key is to pass the `graphql.GraphQLString` into `graphql.GraphQLList()`

The schema becomes:

```
var ColorType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'colors',
  fields: function() {
    return {
      name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
      keys: { type: new graphql.GraphQLList(graphql.GraphQLString)
    };
  }
});
```

Using this query:

*query { colors { name, keys } }*

I get the desired results:

```
{
  name: "colors",
  keys: ["red", "blue"]
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to write your solution up. Saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: @davnicwil Exactly!